# jQuery PrevAll Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a simple rating system like you've seen a thousand times. I have 5 rating "stars" from 1 to 5. When an star is moused over, that star is changed to a "positive" image and all the lower stars should be changed as well. So, when you mouse over a "3" then images 1 through 3 are highlighted. You know what I mean. Anyway, the code below only seems to want to highlight the image that is moused over.

**jQuery:**

```
        $(document).on("mouseover", "input.ranking", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "img/rss_orb_green.png");
        $(this).prevAll("src", "img/rss_orb_green.png");
        $(this).nextAll("src", "img/rss_orb_light_gray.png");
        var score = 0;
        $("input.ranking").each(function (index, element) {
            if ($(element).attr("src") == "img/rss_orb_green.png") {
                    score = score + 1;
            };
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 770px; float: left;">

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$skill1" class="ranking" id="MainContent_skill1" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" type="image" src="img/rss_orb_green.png" state="img/rss_orb_green.png" rank="1">

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$skill2" class="ranking" id="MainContent_skill2" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" type="image" src="img/rss_orb_green.png" state="img/rss_orb_green.png" rank="2">

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$skill3" class="ranking" id="MainContent_skill3" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" type="image" src="img/rss_orb_light_gray.png" state="img/rss_orb_light_gray.png" rank="3">

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$skill4" class="ranking" id="MainContent_skill4" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" type="image" src="img/rss_orb_light_gray.png" state="img/rss_orb_light_gray.png" rank="4">

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$skill5" class="ranking" id="MainContent_skill5" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" type="image" src="img/rss_orb_light_gray.png" state="img/rss_orb_light_gray.png" rank="5">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using prevAll and nextAll correctly.  I would also recommend storing `$(this)` in a variable

```
$(this).prevAll().attr("src", "img/rss_orb_green.png");
$(this).nextAll().attr("src", "img/rss_orb_light_gray.png");
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. It always seems to be something simple I'm overlooking. Thanks so much. If you don't mind, could you explain why using a variable is better? I'm assuming it's a performance recommendation, but I don't understand what's going on under the hood of jQuery.

Comment: @brad yes, storing it in a variable means it doesn't need to be retrieved from the DOM on every line.